# RegEx for extracting an attribute value

Tags: regex, jmeter, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, boost-regex

I am trying to extract the value of id from the code provided below

I have tried the following regular expression but it still comes back as my default value of : id_not_found

id" selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization="(.+?)" />

```
<input type="radio" name="frm.organization" id="selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization{C5DF28FD-26EF-90DA-1214-BD72E0214F17}" value="{C5DF28FD-26EF-90DA-1214-BD72E0214F17}" title="College of St. Jude" ext-ns-multiple="frmorganization">
```

I expect the regex extractor to be able to recognize the id (it is a dynamic id and changes based on the radio button selected)

Comment: added a code snippet that shows that the regex is correct. can you add the code you use to execute your regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we might just want to take `id="` as a left boundary and `"` as a right boundary, then collect our attribute value in the first capturing group `$1`:

```
id="(.+?)"
```

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Iy1yvc/1)

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that how the capturing groups work:

```js
const regex = /id="(.+?)"/gm;
const str = `<input type="radio" name="frm.organization" id="selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization{C5DF28FD-26EF-90DA-1214-BD72E0214F17}" value="{C5DF28FD-26EF-90DA-1214-BD72E0214F17}" title="College of St. Jude" ext-ns-multiple="frmorganization">
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Iy1yvc/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `id="\w+{([A-Z0-9-]+)}"`, if the string before the `id` *could* change.

If the string before the `id` is *always the same* or there are multiple id-strings like that and you only want *this specific one* use `

```js
let html = '<input type="radio" name="frm.organization" id="selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization{C5DF28FD-26EF-90DA-1214-BD72E0214F17}" value="{C5DF28FD-26EF-90DA-1214-BD72E0214F17}" title="College of St. Jude" ext-ns-multiple="frmorganization">';
let rgx = /id="(selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization{([A-Z0-9-]+)})"/;

var result = rgx.exec(html);
if (result) {
    alert('regex matched:\n\nfull-id=' + result[1] + '\n\nvalue=' + result[2]);
} else {
    alert('regex does not match');
}
```

`

To match only GUIDs as IDs you can use `id="selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization{([A-Z0-9-]{8}-[A-Z0-9-]{4}-[A-Z0-9-]{4}-[A-Z0-9-]{4}-[A-Z0-9-]{12})}"`

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern you tried `id" selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization="(.+?)" />` you could make these changes:

`id"` should be `id="`, `organization="` should be `organization{` and you can remove `/>`

You might keep `(.+?)` but you could also use a negated character class to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

You could use match `{`, then use a capturing group and match what is inside using a negated character class `([^{}\n]+)` and then match `}` again:

```
id="selectNOIOrg_do_frm_organization{([^{}\n]+)}"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D8SUyt/1)